# Error: Regarding NDK emulation in android

Tags: android, android-ndk

I just started out android application development. I have a novice experience in developing applications using java. Here for example I wrote a simple Fibonacci program where the numbers are added and displayed. I wrote the coding in java for iteration and recursion, in c for iteration and recursion. And compare their execution time. The program gets installed in emulator and when I try to calculate the value, it just exits. In Logcat it shows the following exceptions and errors thrown. Can anyone tell me what these are how to solve them. I've added the coding below.

FibActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FibActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private EditText input;
    private RadioGroup type;
    private TextView output;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.input = (EditText) super.findViewById(R.id.input);
        this.type = (RadioGroup) super.findViewById(R.id.type);
        this.output = (TextView) super.findViewById(R.id.output);
        Button button = (Button) super.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        String s = this.input.getText().toString();
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
            return;
        }

        final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Calculating...", true);
        final long n = Long.parseLong(s);
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                long result = 0;
                long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
                switch(FibActivity.this.type.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
                    case R.id.type_fib_jr:
                        result = FibLib.fibJR(n);
                    case R.id.type_fib_ji:
                        result = FibLib.fibJI(n);
                    case R.id.type_fib_nr:
                        result = FibLib.fibNR(n);
                    case R.id.type_fib_ni:
                        result = FibLib.fibNI(n);
                }
                t = System.currentTimeMillis() - t;
                return String.format("fib(%d)=%d in %d ms", n, result, t);
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.dismiss();
                FibActivity.this.output.setText(result);
            }

        }.execute();

    }
}
```

com_android_fibnat_FibLib.c

```
#include <com_android_fibnat_FibLib.h>

static jlong fib(jlong n) {
    return n <= 0? 0 : n==1 ? 1 : fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}

JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_android_fibnat_FibLib_fibNR
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass c, jlong n) {
    return fib(n);
}

JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_android_fibnat_FibLib_fibNI
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass c, jlong n) {

    jlong p = -1;
    jlong result = 1;
    jlong i;
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++) {
        jlong sum = result + p;
        p = result;
        result = sum;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here are the list of errors I get
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3NEoejIh-a0S0dOcVlZOVFHU00/view?usp=sharing[^]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're native library (libcom_android_fibnative_FibLib.so) is missing.

Is it inside your APK ? (under `lib/(x86|armeabi|armeabi-v7a)/`, you can look inside your APK by opening it as a .zip file.)

Comment: the libcom_android_fibnative_FibLib.so file exists on all architectures armeabi,armeabi-v7a, mips and x86.

Another Edit:I tried running sample NDK code from google, it also returned errors in the LogCat.

Comment: Are the package name of your FibLib class and the implementations correctly matching ? Since in your C your functions starts with `Java_com_android_fibnat`, it should be `com.android.fibnat`. Does /data/app-lib/com.android.fibnat-1/libcom_android_fibnative_FibLib.so exist ? You can easily check all this and if the functions are correctly exported using my app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xh.nativelibsmonitor.app&hl=en